# SharePoint online can't find SPSite, SPWeb, SPFolder

Tags: forms, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, office365, infopath

I'm using InfoPath 2012, VIsual studio 2012 and SharePoint online.
I'm creating form in infopath that can save files to the SP library, i found this article http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/upload-document-sharepoint-infopath-form.htm , I made all like in this article, but I can't connetc to the SPSite, SPWeb, SPFolder.
This is the code that makes errors:

```
 // Add the file to a document library
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Blog/Shared%20Documents"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPFolder docLib = web.Folders["Documents"];
                        docLib.Files.Add(fileName, data);
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        web.Close(); 
                    }
                    site.Close();
                }
```

Mayby someone have any ideas?
I already download the dll library, but it is not help 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run code behind in an InfoPath form on SharePoint online. You shouldn't use InfoPath at all in SharePoint Online.

Check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56617/can-i-use-infopath-code-behind-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: Ok, if I can't create form in InfoPath, maybe you have any ideas how to create form in SharePoint online with attachments and put them to the another folder?
Best Regards